# Canonical projections for $\mathbb{H}^2_1$ and $\mathbb{S}^2_1$

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

We know that there exists a canonical projection $\pi:\mathbb{S}^2\to\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$. Are there similar transformations for hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2_1$  or pseudosphere $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ in Minkowski 3-space?

Comment: Similar and canonical in what sense? The elliptic plane is a quotient space of the sphere, likewise the hyperbolic plane has quotient spaces too, some of which are important (e.g. Klein Quartic) but a bit less canonical (a Klein quartic has only 168 automorphisms which is also maximal for a surface of that genus, while the elliptic plane can be translated and rotated in any way and you get the same).

Comment: As for the projection which identifies $x$ and $-x$, in the hyperbolic plane you do that by default (but you could also *not* do it and get two disconnected hyperbolic planes), I do not know much about the pseudosphere, but it seems that such a projection should work there.

Comment: Other than that, I think you would basically project the space to itself via identity.